# Determine if there is an integer $n\geq 1$ such that $(\sqrt{2}+1)^{1/n}+(\sqrt{2}-1)^{1/n}\in\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

could you help me with this problem? I have to determine whether there exists a number *n* larger or equal to 1 for which the number
$$
\sqrt[n]{\sqrt{2}+1}+\sqrt[n]{\sqrt{2}-1}
$$
is rational.

I still can't find a solution and would appreciate any kind of help.

Comment: I ran a program for this - quite a few of the results are very near integers for various n values; there are multiple 9's after the decimal point. I don't know why.

Comment: For any integer $n\geq 1$, $(\sqrt{2}+1)^{1/n}+(\sqrt{2}-1)^{1/n}$ is irrational, just see my proof below. It just relies on two facts: $\sqrt{2}\not\in\mathbb{Q}$, $(\sqrt{2}+1)(\sqrt{2}-1)=1\in\mathbb{Q}$.

Answer (score 3):

There are no such $n$s.

Set $\alpha=\sqrt{2}+1,\beta=\sqrt{2}-1,\gamma=\alpha^{1/n},\delta=\beta^{1/n}$.

We have $\alpha\beta = 1$, $\alpha+\beta=2\sqrt{2}$,  hence $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are roots of the polynomial

$$p(x) = x^2-2\sqrt{2}\,x+1$$
while $\gamma$ and $\delta$ are roots of the polynomial
$$ q(x) = x^{2n}-2\sqrt{2}\,x^n+1.\tag{1}$$
Assuming that $\gamma+\delta\in\mathbb{Q}$, we have $\gamma^k+\delta^k\in\mathbb{Q}$ for any integer $k$, since:
$$\gamma^{k+1}+\delta^{k+1} = (\gamma+\delta)(\gamma^{k}+\delta^k)-\gamma\delta(\gamma^{k-1}+\delta^{k-1})\tag{2}$$
and $\gamma\delta=1$. Hence  we have $\gamma^{2n}+\delta^{2n}\in\mathbb{Q}$ as well as $\gamma^{n}+\delta^{n}\in\mathbb{Q}$.

However, due to $(1)$, this cannot happen, since:
$$\gamma^{2n}+\delta^{2n} = 2\sqrt{2}(\gamma^{n}+\delta^{n})-2,\tag{3}$$
and $2\sqrt{2}\not\in\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: (3) can be replaced by the fact that $\gamma^n+\delta^n=\alpha+\beta=2\sqrt2$.

Comment: @QuangHoang: you're right, my argument can be shortened, but it is pretty straighforward anyway.